# A chart engine android stacked bar chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I need toplot a chart using `achartengine` library .

I have several slips `(Stock Sales,Stock Return,Stock Expense,Funds Expense,Stock Usage...)`

When a user selects dates, the chart should show all that slips total (that sales,stock returns, stock usage) between those selected days.
In every day, there has to be a four columns

1. Outgoing Stock
2. Incoming Stock
3. Outgoing Funds
4. Incoming Funds

Here is a picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmDUX.png

How can I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated